# Angular4: Log the time taken by the server to respond

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have a service to get project details like

```
public getProjectDetail(id: number): Observable<IProject> {
    if (id === undefined) {
      return Observable.of(this.initializeProject());
    }
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'api/v1/cmang_api/projects/' + id, { headers: this.headers })
      .map(this.extractResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I want to console the time taken by the server to process the request. Is there any way to log the time?

Comment: Just look in the network tab in your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: If you must console it out `console.time` is your friend, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

Answer (score 0):

At a very basic debugging level you can utilize the [do](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md) operator in combination with [console.time()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time);

```
public getProjectDetail(id: number): Observable<IProject> {
  if (id === undefined) {
    return Observable.of(this.initializeProject());
  }

  // start timer with label 'getProjectDetail()'
  console.time(`getProjectDetail(${id})`);    

  return this.http.get(this.url + 'api/v1/cmang_api/projects/' + id, { headers: this.headers })
    // end time with label 'getProjectDetail()'
    .do(res => console.timeEnd(`getProjectDetail(${id})`))
    .map(this.extractResponse)        
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Keep in mind this will log in development as well as production environments.

Output would look like:

```
getProjectDetail(someIdNumberDisplaysHere): 5171.75ms
```

Hopefully that helps!